# Improve site with SEO microdata

Tags: seo

I need to do SEO Microdata for one site. What is my biggest problem is to choose which type would be on this list http://schema.org/docs/full.html . So let's say that I should choose the type of portfolio, and link the portfolio is as follows: Code:

`<a href = "#" data-remote = "images/portfolio/image1.jpg" class = "portfolio-box" data-toggle = "lightbox" data-gallery = "I" data-title = "Image1"> </ a>`
because the problem of slip-propery is in this link, img, logo, ... Do you like this could be used itemtype "http://schema.org/Product" and how strictly it should all be, if there is more than one type of a section of the site or there is only one appropriate? Thank you in advance ..

Comment: I'm not sure what your actual question is here. Can you please clarify what you're looking for?

Comment: Which type i should use from http://schema.org/docs/full.html to define portfolio and contact page?

Comment: There is no such thing as "SEO microdata" either.

Comment: It's website about internet business...